# SPM Build tool not running when adding package to projec

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, swift-package-plugin

I have created a new project and added this Swift Package to it:

https://github.com/laevandus/SwiftExampleToomasKit

If I build the project it fails to compile the SPM Package saying MyGeneratedEnum is missing.

This enum is generated by build tool attached to the plugin.

If I open the Package.swift for the above repo and build, the enum gets generated and the framework compiles as it should.

Any idea why the build tool is not executed when attaching the package to an iOS project ?